# Knockout-Validation not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using knockout.js with CakePHP and I cannot seem to get [knockout-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) to work. I'm using chrome and knockout-validation is loaded in the scripts and also shows in the network tab. Also, when I remove the "include script" I get all sorts of errors, so I know it's being included.

I have a view model called ReserveViewModel. Here's an example of an input I'm trying to validate. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't flag anything.

```
ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
});

function ReserveViewModel(){

    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true })
                .extend({ minLength: 3 })
                .extend({ pattern: {
                    message: 'Please enter your first name',
                    params: '^[a-zA-Z]'
                }});

    //button to continue to another div with more options
    self.continue = function(){
        self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
        if (self.errors().length == 0) {
            alert('Error found');
        }
    }

}

ko.validation.registerExtenders();

ko.applyBindings(new ReserveViewModel());
```

When I click the "continue" button and the firstName input is blank it still continues. I tried putting an alert on `self.errors().length` and it results in the following error

```
function m(){if(0<arguments.length){if("function"===typeof r)r.apply(c,arguments);else throw Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.");return this}l||e();a.q.bb(m);return k}
```

If it makes a difference, I'm loading this content via an AJAX call through CakePHP. Would that affect it anything? Could it be some kind of closure?

**Edit I got it to work**

I ended up using jQuery to retrieve all the scripts necessary. Then I would use AJAX to populate the div. On the page I was retrieving via AJAX I included the ViewModel file.

It was a strange mixup due to files loading at different times, so I just had to make them load sequentially with jquery.

Comment: @f_martinez Self is there, I must have missed it when copying

Comment: ok then. If `self` is ok then the problem definitely is in your ajax-call. Make sure that loaded script is executed AFTER the hypertext markup is injected into DOM.

Comment: @f_martinez, I did some re-arranging of the order that the scripts load. I have a very strange situation now. No errors are thrown, and knockout appears to be working, although my subscribed items are no longer being triggered upon a change. I have a few divs and buttons that are hidden upon loading, so I know knockout is loading. I didn't touch a line of my knockout code, any suggestions as to why it's not "responding" to changes now?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine now is that you have a conflict of multiple viewmodels applied to same DOM nodes. Could you explain your problem with more details (app structure, viewmodels if more than one, ajax-calls)?